# Fiddler: How to stop a request, do a POST request and then resume the request

Tags: post, fiddler

i need to edit an HTTP POST request with Fiddler but my "editing rules" are not client-side but server-side. So, I have to pause the request, submit its body to my PHP Server, waiting for reply, overwrite the original request body with the new string received by the server and then resume the request for sending to its original recipient.

I've used FiddlerScript Editor to do something like this in the OnBeforeRequest block:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    var reqbody = oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
    if (reqbody.Contains("my-unique-string")) {
        var result = do_post("http://www.mywebserver.it/post.php", reqbody);
        oSession.utilSetRequestBody(result);
    }            
}
```

The result is that the request remains completely stopped and my do_post() is being executed hundred times until I kill Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

What does `do_post` do?

You need to update your `OnBeforeRequest` code to not issue a POST request in reaction to the POST request you yourself generated. You could do that by not calling `do_post` if `oSession.HostnameIs("www.mywebserver.it")`